# Auto-launch apps at iDevice startup

Tags: iphone, ipad, startup, skype, facetime

In another question I asked, Graeme suggested [using alternatives like Skype](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45518/3791) instead of FaceTime for its support for audio-only calls.

Skype has the advantage of being cross-platform, but is there a way in which I could actually make Skype auto-login when my iPad starts, and keep it running continuously like FaceTime? Or is this functionality restricted to in-built apps only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skype is a VOIP app so it is in the [class of apps that actually do run in the background](http://speirs.org/blog/2012/1/2/misconceptions-about-ios-multitasking.html). However you need to start it manually. There's no facility in iOS to start a non-Apple app every time the device starts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Adam. Is there no way even after jailbreaking?

Comment: There may well be but I'm not knowledgable about jail breaking. A quick google suggests it is very likely.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-launch app: 
    To use the features of the External Accessory framework, you must add ExternalAccessory.framework to your Xcode project and waitting for Accessory send RequestAppLaunch IAP2 control message, but it needed a Accessory with MFi.